# How do I figure out how much of a given stock I have in my portfolio of mutual funds and ETFs?

Tags: etf, mutual-funds, quicken

If I own mutual funds or ETFs at some level of investment, which in turn own individual stocks, what is the easiest way to tell how much of each individual stock I own?

I use Quicken, so it would be great if Quicken did this.  It looks like they have a tool called [Morningstar X-ray](https://help.quicken.com/display/WIN/Tell+me+about+analyzing+my+portfolio+with+X-ray+analysis), but when I follow their directions, I don't see any X-ray menu, so maybe they don't support it anymore.

**EDIT**: I discovered that Quicken's X-ray is only in the "premier" version, which is why I can't see it.

Comment: There are some web sites that do this, in both directions.  For example, (1) what funds contain stock XYZ? (2) What are the largest holdings of fund XYZ?  You'll have to do some googling to find them.

Comment: Morningstar's Instant X-Ray still exists: https://tools.morningstar.de/de/xray/editholdings.aspx?LanguageId=de-DE&values=